# Java: Comparing ints mystery

Tags: java, int

I've got a list filled with ints:

```
List collection = new ArrayList();
collection.add(this.score1);
collection.add(this.score2);
collection.add(this.score3);
```

Now I want to compare the highest score with each individual score, to see which one(s) is the highest. Intuitively I tried to do it like so:

```
String highestScore;

if(Collections.max(collection) == this.score1) {
highestScore = "Score 1";
}

if(Collections.max(collection) == this.score2) {
highestScore += ", Score 2";

}

if(Collections.max(collection) == this.score3) {
highestScore += ", Score 3";

}
```

However,

```
Collections.max(collection) == this.score1
Collections.max(collection) == this.score2
Collections.max(collection) == this.score3
```

all give me the error:

> Incompatible operand types Comparable and int

However this seems to work:

```
int highestScoreValue =  Collections.max(collection);
```

Now how can that be?

Why is Java allowing an int to be set to `Collections.max(collection)`, however doesn't allow an int to be compared with `Collections.max(collection)`?

Comment: `List<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<> ();` would probably work. As declared, your list is a `List<Object>`...

Comment: Looks like on `int highestScoreValue = Collections.max(collection);` compiler can infer the return type using the declaration on the LHS. So, the max method in that case returns an `Integer` (which is then auto-unboxed) instead of `Comparable`.

Comment: Don't use raw types. Take assylias's advice and declare the parameterized type of your collections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primitive types can't be stored in Java collections, they automatically get boxed inside respective classes.

Whenever you do `list.add(score)`, `score` is first wrapped into an `Integer` object, then added to the collection.

Now, when you call `Collections.max` an obect of type `<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>` is returned, and you are comparing it to a primitive type with `==` but this operator is only able to compare references to objects or directly primitive types and in your situation, since your `List` parametric type is unspecified, the compiler is not able to unbox the `Integer` instance returned to an `int`.

Possible solutions are to

- cast the returned value to an `Integer`, thus allowing unboxing
- use `equals` method instead that `==` operator so that the score will be boxed to an `Integer` and then compared to the result of `max`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `equals()` for the comparisons:

```
Collections.max(collection).equals(this.score1)
```

Notice that the [`max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) method returns a `Comparable` object, that can't be compared with `==` with an `int`. Another option would be casting it first to an `Integer`. As a side note, this is not the most efficient way for finding the maximum value, you're switching back and forth between primitive types and object types. Better implement your own `max` method for integers.